# Escaping Angled Bracket acts similar to look-ahead

Tags: regex, r, gsub

Why does escaping escaping the angled bracket `>` exhibit the look-ahead like behavior?

*To be clear, I understand that the angled bracket does not necessitate being escaped.

The question is, how is the pattern being interpreted that it yields the match(es) shown*

```
## match bracket, with or without underscore
## replace with "greater_"
strings <- c("ten>eight", "ten_>_eight")
repl    <- "greater_"

## Unescaped. Yields desired results
gsub(">_?", repl, strings)
#  [1] "tengreater_eight"  "ten_greater_eight"

## All four of these yield the same result
gsub("\\>_?",   repl, strings)  # (a)
gsub("\\>(_?)", repl, strings)  # (b)
gsub("\\>(_)?", repl, strings)  # (c)
gsub("\\>?",    repl, strings)  # (d)
gsub("\\>",     repl, strings)  # (e)
#  [1] "tengreater_>eightgreater_"   "ten_greater_>_eightgreater_"

gregexpr("\\>?", strings)
```

Some follow up questions:

```
1.  Why do `(a)` and `(d)` yield the same result? 
2.  Why is the end-of-string matched?
3.  Why do none of `a, b, or c` match the underscore?
```

Comment: `\\>` = word boundary..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\\>` is a word boundary Which matches between a word character(in the left side) and a non-word character (in the right side) or end of the line anchor `$`.

```
> strings <- c("ten>eight", "ten_>_eight")
> gsub("\\>", "greater_", strings)
[1] "tengreater_>eightgreater_"   "ten_greater_>_eightgreater_"
```

In the above example it match only the word boundary exists between a word character after `n` and a non-word character `>` then also the boundary between `t` and end of the line anchor in the first element. And it matches between `_` (also a word character) and `>` then  between `t` and end of the line anchor (ie, `$`) in the second element. Finally it replaces the matched boundaries with the string you specified.

**A simple example:**

```
> gsub("\\>", "*", "f:r(:")
[1] "f*:r*(:"
```

Consider the below input string. (*`w` means a word character, `N` means a non-word character*)

```
    f:r(:
w___|||||
     |w|N
     N |
       |
       N
```

So `\\>` matches between,

- `f` and `:`
- `r` and `(`

**Example 2:**

```
> gsub("\\>", "*", "f") 
[1] "f*"
```

Input string:

```
f$
||----End of the line anchor
w
```

Replacing the matched boundary with `*` will give the above result.

Comment: Thanks Avinash.  I was familiar with `\b` but not with `\>`.  Very useful, thank you