# sed not matching on < or >

Tags: regex, sed

I have this in a configuration file:

```
<virtual-machine-pool mypool>
virtual-machine machine1
</virtual-machine-pool>

<virtual-machine machine1>
host 17.17.52.177 m34.mydomain.com
</virtual-machine>
```

My scripts seems to ignore the < and > symbols.

```
sed -e "/\(\<virtual-machine machine1\>\)/{:a;n;/<\/virtual-machine>/ba;i\\\n\   <virtual-machine machine-new\>\n\   host 1.2.3.4 m40.mydomain.com\n\   include /etc/virtuals/config.backoff\n\   <\\\virtual-machine\>" -e '}' file
```

I get the output:

```
<virtual-machine-pool mypool>
virtual-machine machine1
</virtual-mta>

   <virtual-machine machine-new>
   host 1.2.3.4 m40.mydomain.com
   include /etc/virtuals/config.backoff
   <\virtual-mta>

<virtual-machine machine1>

   <virtual-machine machine-new>
   host 1.2.3.4 m40.mydomain.com
   include /etc/virtuals/config.backoff
   <\virtual-machine>
   host 17.17.52.177 m34.mydomain.com
</virtual-machine>
```

The desired output is:

```
<virtual-machine-pool mypool>
virtual-machine machine1
</virtual-mta>

<virtual-machine machine1>
   host 17.17.52.177 m34.mydomain.com
</virtual-machine>

   <virtual-machine machine-new>
   host 1.2.3.4 m40.mydomain.com
   include /etc/virtuals/config.backoff
   <\virtual-mta>
```

It seems to me that my script is ignoring the < and > and then finding the match twice and putting it in twice.

This is on OSX with gnu-sed --default-names installed

Thanks for any advice or help.

John

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26237735/escaping-angled-bracket-acts-similar-to-look-ahead

Answer (score 2):

Don't backslash the angle brackets in sed. `\<` and `\>` have special meaning: beginning and end of a word.

Comment: Ok I removed those but still getting the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks choroba.  That did help after all.  I had to replace the </virtual-machine> with ^$.  After that it started working.